# How can I extract a sublist with the lowest integer value from a nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a nested list as follows:

```
foods = [['Category', 'Carbs', 'Calories'], ['SWEET POTATO', '23.4', '100'], ['TOMATOES', '5.1', '23'], ['BEETS', '16.28', '65'], ['LETTUCE', '2.23', '13']]
```

I want to find and print the sublist with the lowest Calorie count. I have tried the following:

```
    lowcal = foods[0]
for x in foods:
    if x[2] < lowcal[2]:
        lowcal = x
    else:
        continue
print (lowcal)
```

But I am getting the wrong output, I am getting: `['SWEET POTATO', '23.4', '100']

When I should be getting: ['LETTUCE', '2.23', '13']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `min()` on your list with `key` as third element:

```
min([x for x in foods[1:]], key=lambda x: int(x[2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your values for `Carbs` and `Calories` are strings (you have them in quotes!), rather than integers. Also, you start with `lowcal = foods[0]` which is your headers, not a food with calories and carbs. I'd suggest the following:

```
foods = [
    ['Category', 'Carbs', 'Calories'],
    ['SWEET POTATO', '23.4', 100],
    ['TOMATOES', '5.1', 23],
    ['BEETS', '16.28', 65],
    ['LETTUCE', '2.23', 13]
]
lowcal = foods[1]
for x in foods[2:]:
    if int(x[2]) < int(lowcal[2]):
        lowcal = x
>>> print (lowcal)
['LETTUCE', '2.23', 13]
```

Victory! Hope that helps, happy coding!

Comment: The problem is for this task I am working on a .csv file given to me so I cannot remove the quotes around the calorie integers. I have to convert them to ints in my code but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: ah, you just presented it as a list of lists. In fact, you said you have a list of lists, not a csv. I see you chose a correct answer already, but I modified mine to work as well.